# Hi all, how can I get all files from directory in android

Tags: android, readfile, android-external-storage

how can I get all files from directory in android? For example, if I want read file from DCIM/Camera.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        Log.e("dir", dir.toString());
        Log.e("dir", Arrays.toString(dir.list()));   
    }
```

Log

```
03-12 22:21:33.370 14224-14224/com.example.kirill.javagallery E/dir: /storage/emulated/0
03-12 22:21:33.370 14224-14224/com.example.kirill.javagallery E/dir: null
```

Why ExternalStorageDirectory is empty  ?

```
Manifest
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it